# OData $expand not working for User Field in SharePoint App

Tags: sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-hosted-app, app, sharepoint-rest-api, odata

I am trying to use the OData `$expand` query option to fetch the Title of a SharePoint User Field. The field name is, **Author (Created By)**. However, on using the `$expand` option, I am getting the following error,

> The $expand query is not valid for field 'Author'.

Following is the URL that I am using to fetch the data.

```
https://appUrl/_api/Sp.AppContextSite(@target)/Web/Lists(guid'guid')/items?$select=Number1,Author/Title&$expand=Author/ID&@target='targetSiteUrl'
```

Interestingly, if I use the following URL from a SharePoint Content Editor Web Part then everything is working fine!

```
http://targetSiteUrl/_api/Web/Lists(guid'guid')/items?$select=Number1,Author/Title&$expand=Author/ID
```

So, my question is, am I doing something wrong or we cannot use `$expand` from within the scope of a SharePoint App? As of now, it works fine directly from the site but not from the add-in.

Comment: try this once https://appUrl/_api/Sp.AppContextSite(@target)/Web/Lists(guid'guid')/items?$select=Number1,Author/Title,Author/ID&$expand=Author&@target='targetSiteUrl'

Comment: @TARUN it didn't worked. Getting same error.

Comment: ?$expand=Author&$select=Author/Id,Author/Title

Comment: @Marco I have used both, `$expand=Author` as well as `$expand=Author/ID` None of them worked. Getting the same error!

Comment: if you make the call with no parameters, just items did it show the author column?

Comment: @Marco No in that case, there is no Author column. However, it does gives this property, `AuthorId` with a number id value.

Comment: Can that be a permission issue with your app? does it work if you remove Author field from API call?

Comment: @AkshayRandive My App has the permission to read and write at a List level. Now will test with a more elevated permission. The call is working anyways whether or not I include `Author`. Issue is coming when I am including $expand. Otherwise, I am getting all the selected fields except Author.

Comment: @AkshayRandive No still not working. Gave it User profile read permission as well as SiteCollection read permission, yields the same error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that for the method **items**, used in the given URL, I was sending the type as POST instead of GET in my app!

However, from the Content Editor Web Part, I am not setting this value so by default GET is correctly getting passed.

You can also check the detailed answer [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/ecd7a899-92d5-4690-a8fb-b2eee405bc61/odata-expand-not-working-for-user-field-in-sharepoint-app?forum=appsforsharepoint#ecd7a899-92d5-4690-a8fb-b2eee405bc61).